# Complement of $n\times n$ matrices vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$  be the vector space of all $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb{R}$, and define the scalar product of two matrices $A,B$ by
>
> $\langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(AB)$, where $\operatorname{tr}$ is the trace (sum of the diagonal elements).
> Describe the orthogonal complement of the subspace of diagonal matrices. What is the dimension of this orthogonal complement?

I do not understand what is the description of the "orthogonal complement of the subspace of diagonal matrices". In what concerns the dimension I remembered the theorem that states:$\dim W+\dim W^{\bot}=\dim V$ in which $W$ is a subspace of $V$.

**Questions**:

**1)** How do I answer this question?

**2)** Could someone provide me a proof?

Thanks in advance!

Questions

Comment: The vector space of  diagonal matrices has a canonical basis. You have to find the vectors from the canonical basis of $ M_n (\mathbb {R} ) $ that are orthogonal over those vectors. They generate the complement.

Comment: @rafa     What is a canonical basis?

Comment: the subspace of diagonal matrices: $\mathfrak D=\{D \mid D_{i,j}=0, \forall i\neq j\}$, its complement: $\mathfrak D^\perp = \{M\mid \langle M,D\rangle=0, \forall D \in \mathfrak D\}$.

Comment: @Surb          But Shall I answer $\mathfrak D^\perp = \{M\mid \langle M,D\rangle=0, \forall D \in \mathfrak D\}$? What about its dimension?

Comment: Dimension of the complement is $n^{2}-n$

Comment: @Riju Why $n^{2}-n$?

Comment: What is the dimension of diagonal subspace. It is $n$, as I have written one of its basis in the answer. Any complement has dimension then $n^{2}-n$.

Comment: By the way is $\langle A,B \rangle = Tr(AB)$ an innerproduct? It doesn't seem so!

Comment: @Riju: it should probably be $\mathrm{tr}(AB^T)$ or $\mathrm{tr}(A^TB)$.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking because the above doesn't satisfy $\langle x,x \rangle =0 \implies x=0$.

Comment: @PedroGomes You should check the definition of the inner product that you have written!

Comment: @Riju I have checked it for $2\times 2$ matrix and it complies with the inner product properties. However I do not know if a matrix of such dimension is representative.

Comment: @PedroGomes $\langle E_{12}, E_{12} \rangle =0$ but $E_{12}$ is not the zero matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E_{ij}$ denote the matrix with $1$ in $ij^{th}$ position and $0$ otherwise. For $1 \leq i \leq n$ and $1 \leq j \leq n$, this is a basis for $M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R})$.
And $E_{ii}(1\leq i \leq n)$ forms a basis for the diagonal subspace. Also $E_{ij}E_{kl}=\delta_{jk}E_{il}$, where $\delta_{jk}$ is $1$ if $j=k$, otherwise it is $0$. So the basis for the subspace is clearly a orthogonal basis. Now, the extended basis for the whole space is as described above. Now just use the Gram-schimdt Orthogonalization process to orthogonalize this basis keeping the basis for the subspace same. Whatever vectors you get except the $E_{ii}$'s is a basis for the complement.

Comment: I am not understanding your answer. Could you use matrix notation? I do not use Kronecker Delta stil. Those are the reasons I down voted.

Comment: I just wrote what $\delta_{jk}$ means.

Comment: How do I apply Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization process in the diagonal basis in this specific case? How do you get $n^2-n$ as dimension of the complement, I mean the $n^2$?

Comment: Ok what is the dimension of the vector space $M_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R})$? What is the dimension of the subspace? If $V=U \oplus W$, then $dim(V)=dim(U)+dim(W)$, follows from the dimension theorem.

Comment: Sorry but I have not yet covered that theorem.

Comment: I do not know from where you get the n^2 as a dimension, because the standard basis of a matrix vector space is the number of matrices which matches the number of diagonal elements.

Comment: I wrote the basis above for $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$. It consists of $n^{2}$ elements!

Answer (score 4):

You can check by direct computation that a matrix $A=(a_{ij})_{1\le i,j\le n}$ is orthogonal to the diagonal matrix $D=(\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_n)$ if and only if
$$\lambda_1a_{11}+\dots+\lambda_n a_{nn}=0.$$
Hence it is orthogonal to all diagonal matrices if and only if $a_{11}=\dots= a_{nn}=0$, i.e. its diagonal elements are $0$. Clearly this subspace is isomorphic to $\mathbf R^{n^2-n}$.

Comment: How do you get $n^2-n$?

Comment: This is the number of non-diagonal  elements in an $n\times n$ matrix.

Comment: By a ‘standard basis’, I suppose you mean matrices $E_{ij}$  with all coefficients equal to $0$, except it has $1$ in the $(i,j)$ position?

Comment: yes, but I have already got it

Comment: It's the same as what  I said: you remove the $E_{ii}$s from this basis, and you obtain  your basis  of the orthogonal complement.